# What is the different between the two Asynchoronous Requests?

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, request

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest
```

and

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {}
```

I see that one is specific to urlRequests but could one have also used the dispatch_async function to get a data from URL then do UI related stuff in an asynchoronous fashion?

Thanks in advance,

Ace

Comment: If you want to know wether it calls on the main thread you can print out NSThread.isMainThread() inside the handler for sendAsynchronousRequest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you said the NSURLConnection method is specifically for sending async request and acts at a higher level of abstraction. Meaning a lot of heavy lifting is done for you under the hood.

Also what you do in the example is dispatching the call of the block you would supply asynchronously, but the block itself would be executed on the main queue, which would not be asynchronous.

You could for example download something in the background with the asynchronous request and then do UI related stuff on the main queue with your dispatch_async call.

So to speak: dispatch_async is part of the rather low-level GCD framework that can be used for a variety of things, like dispatching arbitrary codeblocks on different queues etc. [See here for reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html)